# How to avoid use of GPS using LocationClient of Google Play Services?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I have an app that runs in background and I want to avoid use of GPS.

According to official doc [LocationRequest API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html):

> (...) Applications **cannot** specify the exact location sources, such as GPS, that are used by the LocationClient. (...)

Is it really impossible to prevent the app from using GPS when using Google Play Services Fused Location Provider?

In my case, I know the Wi-Fi is always ON and it should be enough to retrieve a good position using NETWORK_PROVIDER. May I use the old-school location retriever to avoid use of GPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), which provides much more control, but requires **far more** code. If you don't request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, the GPS will never be used.

Check out this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

It should be noted, if you designate `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` with `LocationRequest`, it will intentionally obfuscate the location result.

> Location requests from applications with ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and
>   not ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION will be automatically throttled to a slower
>   interval, and the location object will be obfuscated to only show a
>   coarse level of accuracy.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli I'm sorry, you actually *want* a hack? The Fused Location Provider is not meant to be used in the way you want. Since it's not open source, it'll require some work to hack.

Comment: Fused Location Provider is perfect, except you just can't say "don't use GPS, never". A little hack here won't kill anyone. I'm pretty sure with some reflections would be possible. Well, let this question open. Who knows in near future?

Comment: If you don't request the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission the Fused Location Provider will never return a GPS location.